# How do I Resolve a dependency issue with Ubuntu SDK, chroot, CMakelists, and the Emulator?

Tags: application-development, dependencies, programming, ubuntu-sdk, chroot

I am trying to build `lp:ubuntu-filemanager-app` on the ubuntu sdk for running on the emulator. The libraries I need are installed on my system, and in the phablet-shell. I can run the application in QMLScene.

However, when I try to build the application for the ubuntu touch emulator, I receive the following dependency error:

```
/home/akiva/Programming/ubuntu-filemanager-app/src/plugin/folderlistmodel/dirmodel.cpp:45: error: taglib/attachedpictureframe.h: No such file or directory
 #include <taglib/attachedpictureframe.h>
                                         ^
```

[image]

1. Does it make a difference for adding these dependencies if I use CMakeLists over QMLproject or .pro, or is it the same process across the board?
2. How do I add this dependency?

   - Do I need to go to the projects page?
   - Do I need to address it in Run or Build?
3. Why does this depency issue happen in the first place? Is CMakelists configured improperly?
4. Can I submit a patch to correct this issue in the future? How?

Comment: For any future references, the readme states that the following should be installed for desktop `sudo apt-get install libtag1-dev libpam0g-dev python3` - seems that `libtag1-dev` is the one needed to fix the above error.